# add specific columns from datatable to gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I am looking to return a datatable to a gridview, however I dont need all of the columns in the datatable in the gridview.

how would be the best approach to do this programatically?

my code at the moment is this

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
dt = GetValues()
gvContactList.DataSource = dt
```

The columns that I need to return are indexed as follows 0, 6, 7, 9

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary datatable (that has columns you are intersted in ) and populate the temporary table with the rows from the actual table.

Now bind the grid with datasource as temp datatable.

Comment: i had just seen another solution with a similar idea thank  you